# Is it possible to get Android Glide to wait for/reload an image that is saving in another thread?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm using `Glide` in a binding adapter for a `RecyclerView` in Android.

The `RecyclerView` loads when the user navigates out of a detail fragment, back up into a Gallery fragment that shows thumbnails of what just happened in the detail fragment.

Sometimes when the `RecyclerView` is loading, one of the images in the `RecyclerView` is still being written in another thread (a Kotlin `coroutine` if it matters) that was started by the detail fragment.

`Glide` finds the image, and displays it, even when it's incomplete, leading to partial or (more often) empty thumbnails in the Gallery's `RecyclerView`.

Is there a way I can get the binding adapter to wait for the image to finish writing in the other thread before it loads it, or to re-load it when it's finished?
If it matters, the images are `PNGs`.

Here is my code from the `adapter` class:

```
@BindingAdapter("memoThumb")
fun memoThumb(view: ImageView, memo: Memo) {
  val imageUrl = "${getPath(memo.uuid)}$THUMB_NAME"
  if (imageUrl.isNotEmpty()) {
    Glide.with(view.context)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .apply(RequestOptions()
                    .signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            )
            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
            .into(view)
  }
}
```

Thanks!
John

Comment: can you not use futuretarget http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/request/FutureTarget.html and then display only once the target has loaded? https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to that suggestion? I've been looking at FutureTargets and I can't figure out how to apply them to my problem. Thanks

Comment: you should add what you're confused about to your question...

Answer (score 4):

> Background Threads Loading images on background threads is also
>   straight forward using submit(int, int):

```
FutureTarget<Bitmap> futureTarget =
  Glide.with(context)
    .asBitmap()
    .load(url)
    .submit(width, height);

 Bitmap bitmap = futureTarget.get();
```

> // Do something with the Bitmap and then when you're done with it:

```
Glide.with(context).clear(futureTarget);
```

> You can also start
>   asynchronous loads on background threads the same way you would on a
>   foreground thread if you don’t need the Bitmap or Drawable on the
>   background thread itself:

```
Glide.with(context)
  .asBitmap()
  .load(url)
  .into(new Target<Bitmap>() {
    ...
  });
```

[from glide(v4) docs](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html#background)

please let me know what part is confusing you and also whether you're using glide v3 or v4

Comment: I don't want to load images on a background thread. I want to load images on a foreground thread once they have finished saving on a background thread. Is that the same thing? Or are they sufficiently similar that I can think of them as the same thing?